# An invalid statement is raised with SQL Server when using sum operation and order by with alias

Tags: sql, sql-server

While running the following query:

```
    SELECT
    (
        CASE
            WHEN ( ( convert(float, ( ( JSON_VALUE(convert(varchar(max), multi_pod.struc_ppod), '$."bbred"') ) ) ) >= 0 )
                   AND ( convert(float, ( ( JSON_VALUE(convert(varchar(max), multi_pod.struc_ppod), '$."bbred"') ) ) ) <= 1000 ) ) THEN
                '58'
            WHEN ( ( convert(float, ( ( JSON_VALUE(convert(varchar(max), multi_pod.struc_ppod), '$."bbred"') ) ) ) >= 1001 )
                   AND ( convert(float, ( ( JSON_VALUE(convert(varchar(max), multi_pod.struc_ppod), '$."bbred"') ) ) ) <= 10000 ) ) THEN
                '59'
            ELSE
                'Other'
        END
    ) AS cc_1658532399112,
    SUM(CAST(((JSON_VALUE(convert(varchar(max), multi_pod.struc_ppod), '$."bbred"'))) AS FLOAT)) AS "group_by_1658532512558_0"
FROM
    acc.pod.mnnorway_tup_vw multi_pod
ORDER BY
    (
        CASE
            WHEN ( ( convert(float, ( ( JSON_VALUE(convert(varchar(max), multi_pod.struc_ppod), '$."bbred"') ) ) ) >= 0 )
                   AND ( convert(float, ( ( JSON_VALUE(convert(varchar(max), multi_pod.struc_ppod), '$."bbred"') ) ) ) <= 1000 ) ) THEN
                0
            WHEN ( ( convert(float, ( ( JSON_VALUE(convert(varchar(max), multi_pod.struc_ppod), '$."bbred"') ) ) ) >= 1001 )
                   AND ( convert(float, ( ( JSON_VALUE(convert(varchar(max), multi_pod.struc_ppod), '$."bbred"') ) ) ) <= 10000 ) ) THEN
                1
            ELSE
                2
        END
    ) ASC;
```

I am getting the following exception:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
> Column 'acc.pod.mnnorway_tup_vw.struc_ppod' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

When I am removing the **SUM** statement, the query executes fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the integer value 0, 1 and 2 from the query with '58', '59' and 'Other' has resolved my issue.

```
SELECT

    (
        CASE
            WHEN ( ( convert(float, ( ( JSON_VALUE(convert(varchar(max), multi_pod.struc_ppod), '$."bbred"') ) ) ) >= 0 )
                   AND ( convert(float, ( ( JSON_VALUE(convert(varchar(max), multi_pod.struc_ppod), '$."bbred"') ) ) ) <= 1000 ) ) THEN
                '58'
            WHEN ( ( convert(float, ( ( JSON_VALUE(convert(varchar(max), multi_pod.struc_ppod), '$."bbred"') ) ) ) >= 1001 )
                   AND ( convert(float, ( ( JSON_VALUE(convert(varchar(max), multi_pod.struc_ppod), '$."bbred"') ) ) ) <= 10000 ) ) THEN
                '59'
            ELSE
                'Other'
        END
    ) AS cc_1658532399112,
    SUM(CAST(((JSON_VALUE(convert(varchar(max), multi_pod.struc_ppod), '$."bbred"'))) AS FLOAT)) AS "group_by_1658532512558_0"
FROM
    acc.pod.mnnorway_tup_vw multi_pod
GROUP BY (
    CASE
        WHEN ( ( convert(float, ( ( JSON_VALUE(convert(varchar(max), multi_pod.struc_ppod), '$."bbred"') ) ) ) >= 0 )
                   AND ( convert(float, ( ( JSON_VALUE(convert(varchar(max), multi_pod.struc_ppod), '$."bbred"') ) ) ) <= 1000 ) ) THEN
                '58'
            WHEN ( ( convert(float, ( ( JSON_VALUE(convert(varchar(max), multi_pod.struc_ppod), '$."bbred"') ) ) ) >= 1001 )
                   AND ( convert(float, ( ( JSON_VALUE(convert(varchar(max), multi_pod.struc_ppod), '$."bbred"') ) ) ) <= 10000 ) ) THEN
                '59'
        ELSE
            'Other'
    END
)
ORDER BY
    (
    CASE
            WHEN ( ( convert(float, ( ( JSON_VALUE(convert(varchar(max), multi_pod.struc_ppod), '$."bbred"') ) ) ) >= 0 )
                   AND ( convert(float, ( ( JSON_VALUE(convert(varchar(max), multi_pod.struc_ppod), '$."bbred"') ) ) ) <= 1000 ) ) THEN
                '58'
            WHEN ( ( convert(float, ( ( JSON_VALUE(convert(varchar(max), multi_pod.struc_ppod), '$."bbred"') ) ) ) >= 1001 )
                   AND ( convert(float, ( ( JSON_VALUE(convert(varchar(max), multi_pod.struc_ppod), '$."bbred"') ) ) ) <= 10000 ) ) THEN
                '59'
            ELSE
                'Other'
    END
) ASC;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `SUM` without a `GROUP BY` implies that you are grouping by the empty set `()`.

SQL disallows you from selecting or ordering in a grouped query anything other than a grouping value or an aggregated value.

It seems that the value that you are selecting is what you actually want to group by. So you need to add a `GROUP BY` clause. To prevent lots of repetition, you can use `CROSS APPLY (VALUES` to add calculated columns to the query. They can even refer one to the next.

```sql
SELECT
    v2.cc_1658532399112,
    SUM(v1.bbred) AS group_by_1658532512558_0

FROM
    acc.pod.mnnorway_tup_vw multi_pod

CROSS APPLY (VALUES (
    CONVERT(float, JSON_VALUE(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), multi_pod.struc_ppod), '$.bbred'))
) ) v1(bbred)

CROSS APPLY (VALUES (
    CASE
    WHEN v1.bbred >= 0 AND v1.bbred <= 1000
      THEN '58'
    WHEN v1.bbred >= 1001 AND v1.bbred <= 10000
      THEN '59'
    ELSE   'Other'
    END
) ) v2(cc_1658532399112)

GROUP BY
    v2.cc_1658532399112
ORDER BY
    v2.cc_1658532399112;
```

Side note: values between `1000` and `1001` fall through the cracks. Perhaps you want `WHEN v1.bbred > 1000 AND v1.bbred <= 10000 THEN '59'` instead.